# How could I modify the formula of A star algorithm to what I need below?

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star, motion-planning

I'm working on A star algorithm. I'm trying to build a trajectory for drone depending on A star. I have implemented my code below. I need to consider the height of obstacles and modify my equation :

`F= G+H` to `F=H+G+E`

E: represents the elevation of obstacles. We have the drone is flying in a specific altitude over a map, if the obstacle was very high(it means its risk very high) the distance between the obstacle and the drone is too close, so the drone will prefer to fly over the short obstacle. If the obstacle higher than the altitude of the drone, it will turn around.

I added an elevation map with random height generation and drone_altitude, but it doesn't work with me. Could I get some assistance, please?.

The A-star Python Code:

```
import numpy

grid = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

heuristic = [[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4],
             [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3],
             [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2],
             [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
             [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]]

init = [0,0]                           
goal = [len(grid)-1,len(grid[0])-1]     

delta = [[-1 , 0],   #up 
         [ 0 ,-1],   #left
         [ 1 , 0],   #down
         [ 0 , 1]]   #right

delta_name = ['^','<','V','>']  #The name of above actions

cost = 1   #Each step costs you one

drone_height = 60

def search():
    #open list elements are of the type [g,x,y] 


    closed = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]


    action = [[-1 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    #We initialize the starting location as checked
    closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1



    expand=[[-1 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]


    elvation = numpy.random.randint(0, 100+1, size=(5, 6))
    print(elvation)
    # we assigned the cordinates and g value
    x = init[0]
    y = init[1]
    g = 0
    h = heuristic[x][y]
    e = elvation[x][y]
    f = g + h + e

    #our open list will contain our initial value
    open = [[f, g, h, x, y]]


    found  = False   #flag that is set when search complete
    resign = False   #Flag set if we can't find expand
    count = 0

    #print('initial open list:')
    #for i in range(len(open)):
            #print('  ', open[i])
    #print('----')



    while found is False and resign is False:

        #Check if we still have elements in the open list
        if len(open) == 0:    #If our open list is empty, there is nothing to expand.
            resign = True
            print('Fail')
            print('############# Search terminated without success')
            print()
        else: 
            #if there is still elements on our list
            #remove node from list
            open.sort()             
            open.reverse()          #reverse the list
            next = open.pop()       
            #print('list item')
            #print('next')


            x = next[3]
            y = next[4]
            g = next[1]

            expand[x][y] = count
            count+=1

            #Check if we are done
            if x == goal[0] and y == goal[1]:
                found = True
                print(next) #The three elements above this "if".
                print('############## Search is success')
                print()

            else:
                #expand winning element and add to new open list
                for i in range(len(delta)):      
                    x2 = x + delta[i][0]
                    y2 = y + delta[i][1]

                    #if x2 and y2 falls into the grid
                    if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >=0 and y2 <= len(grid[0])-1:
                        #if x2 and y2 not checked yet and there is not obstacles
                        if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0 and e < drone_height:
                            g2 = g + cost             #we increment the cose
                            h2 = heuristic[x2][y2]
                            e2 = elvation[x2][y2]
                            f2 = g2 + h2 + e2

                            open.append([f2,g2,h2,x2,y2])   #we add them to our open list
                            #print('append list item')
                            #print([g2,x2,y2])
                            #Then we check them to never expand again
                            closed[x2][y2] = 1
                            action[x2][y2] = i
    for i in range(len(expand)):
        print(expand[i])
    print()
    policy=[[' ' for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    x=goal[0]
    y=goal[1]
    policy[x][y]='*'
    while x !=init[0] or y !=init[1]:
        x2=x-delta[action[x][y]][0]
        y2=y-delta[action[x][y]][1]
        policy[x2][y2]= delta_name[action[x][y]]
        x=x2
        y=y2
    for i in range(len(policy)):
        print(policy[i])




search()
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? What did you find out?

Comment: @MrSmith42 I found it, it is also considered the high random elevations.